# Column "INVOICE.DATE_OF_ISSUE" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could someone explain me what i'm doing wrong? i'm completly new in this and i don't know what to do.

I'm trying to show Invoice : nr_invoice and invoice value, issued between 17 July 1995 and 24 July 1995, where the net value is more than 50, all sorted by date.

```
SELECT INVOICE.NR_INVOICE, COUNT(COMMODITY.PRICE)
FROM INVOICE FULL JOIN LINE_INVOICE ON INVOICE.NR_INVOICE = LINE_INVOICE.FNR_INVOICE
 LEFT JOIN COMMODITY ON LINE_INVOICE.FID_TOWAR = COMMODITY.ID_COMMODITY
WHERE INVOICE.DATE_OF_ISSUE BETWEEN '1995-07-17' AND '1995-07-24'
  and COMMODITY.PRICE > 50
GROUP BY INVOICE.NR_INVOICE
ORDER BY INVOICE.DATE_OF_ISSUE
```

Here is an error

> Column "INVOICE.DATE_OF_ISSUE" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use outer joins for this query.  Your `where` clause is turning them into inner joins anyway.

To solve your particular problem, you need either to include `DATE_OF_ISSUE` in the `GROUP BY` or use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT i.NR_INVOICE, COUNT(c.PRICE)
FROM INVOICE i JOIN
     LINE_INVOICE li
     ON i.NR_INVOICE = li.FNR_INVOICE JOIN
     COMMODITY c
     ON li.FID_TOWAR = c.ID_COMMODITY
WHERE i.DATE_OF_ISSUE BETWEEN '1995-07-17' AND '1995-07-24' AND
      c.PRICE > 50
GROUP BY i.NR_INVOICE, i.DATE_OF_ISSUE
ORDER BY i.DATE_OF_ISSUE;
```

EDIT:

Your specific question is:

> I'm trying to show Invoice : nr_invoice and invoice value, issued
>   between 17 July 1995 and 24 July 1995, where the net value is more
>   than 50, all sorted by date.

The query for this would use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT i.NR_INVOICE, SUM(c.PRICE)
FROM INVOICE i JOIN
     LINE_INVOICE li
     ON i.NR_INVOICE = li.FNR_INVOICE JOIN
     COMMODITY c
     ON li.FID_TOWAR = c.ID_COMMODITY
WHERE i.DATE_OF_ISSUE BETWEEN '1995-07-17' AND '1995-07-24' 
GROUP BY i.NR_INVOICE, i.DATE_OF_ISSUE
HAVING SUM(c.PRICE) > 50
ORDER BY i.DATE_OF_ISSUE;
```

Note:  If you have a quantity value on the invoice line, then you need to take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the column because it's not in the GROUPING (as the error stated). You can order by aggregate of the column (min or max based on your needs) though. Like this:

```
SELECT INVOICE.NR_INVOICE, COUNT(COMMODITY.PRICE)
FROM INVOICE FULL JOIN LINE_INVOICE ON INVOICE.NR_INVOICE = LINE_INVOICE.FNR_INVOICE
 LEFT JOIN COMMODITY ON LINE_INVOICE.FID_TOWAR = COMMODITY.ID_COMMODITY
WHERE INVOICE.DATE_OF_ISSUE BETWEEN '1995-07-17' AND '1995-07-24'
  and COMMODITY.PRICE > 50
GROUP BY INVOICE.NR_INVOICE
ORDER BY MIN(INVOICE.DATE_OF_ISSUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now i know what i'm doing wrong. So in Order By clause i must use agregate functions right?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT INVOICE.NR_INVOICE, COUNT(COMMODITY.PRICE)
FROM INVOICE FULL JOIN LINE_INVOICE ON INVOICE.NR_INVOICE = LINE_INVOICE.FNR_INVOICE
 LEFT JOIN COMMODITY ON LINE_INVOICE.FID_TOWAR = COMMODITY.ID_COMMODITY
WHERE INVOICE.DATE_OF_ISSUE BETWEEN '1995-07-17' AND '1995-07-24'
  and COMMODITY.PRICE > 50
GROUP BY INVOICE.NR_INVOICE
ORDER BY min(INVOICE.DATE_OF_ISSUE)
```